# Removing duplicate values and finding what key has the most values in python

Tags: python, list, directory, duplicates

I have this code that gets information from a text file that has values like key1:value1 and so on, but some of them are presented multiple times under 1 key. How can I remove duplicates and after that how can I sort which key has the most and least values?

```
def function1(file):
    with open("file_name.txt") as file:
        name = file.read()
    d = {}
    for x in name.split():
        key, value = x.split(':')
        try:
            values = d[key]
        except KeyError:
            values = d[key] = []
        values.append(value)
    return d
```

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python remove duplicate count", you’ll find examples that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have input like:

```
lines = '''
key1:val1
key2:val2
key3:val3
key1:val4
key1:val5
key2:val6
'''.strip().split()
```

Something like this should get you started:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for line in lines:
    k,v = line.split(':')
    d[k].append(v)

items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i:len(i[1]))
print(items)
```

Output (sorted by fewest to most values, add `reverse=True` to `sort` for most to fewest)

```
[
  ('key3', ['val3']), 
  ('key2', ['val2', 'val6']), 
  ('key1', ['val1', 'val4', 'val5'])
]
```

Comment: What if I have like
{'basketball': {'first', 'second', 'third'}, 'football': {'First', 'third', 'second', 'fourth', 'fifth'}, ... and so on, how can I return a list that has the most elements(values) in it like ['football'] right now. It would return like ['football', 'volleyball', 'whatever'] if they all have 5 elements and these are the maximum ones

Comment: If you have `items` (from the code above), you could create it with something like `your_list = [k for (k,v) in items]`.  If not, and you have `d` (also from above), you could use something like: `sorted(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the counter module:

```
from collections import Counter
x = Counter(mylist)
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

One improvement, compared to your code is that I used `defaultdict`,
automatically generating a value for an non-existing key.

Another improvement is splitting using `re.split`, so the input row
can have the colon surrounded with spaces.

An important detail in your question is that you want to count
values **without** repetirions (as I assume, separately for each key).
So the program has to:

- check whether particular value has already been saved under
  the current key,
- save the current value (add to the list) only if it did not occur before.

So, using `Counter` is in my opinion not a good idea, because it counts
how many times **a value has been repeated**, irrespective of the key
under which it occurred, whereas we should count how many **different
values** have been read under each key.

In the following program:

- *filterValues* function reads lines from the input file, stores
  value arrays under the current key and returns the dictionary,
- *findMinMax* function finds 2 tuples (key / value list), one for
  the shortes list and another for the longest.

Here is the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

def filterValues(fn):
    with open(fn) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    d = defaultdict(list)  # key -> values
    for line in lines:
        key, value = re.split('\s*:\s*',line.strip())
        values = d[key]
        if value not in values:  # Save value, w/o repetitions
            values.append(value)
    return d

def findMinMax(d):
    t1 = min(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
    t2 = max(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
    return t1, t2

d = filterValues('file_name.txt')
print(dict(d))
t1, t2 = findMinMax(d)
print(f'Min. count: {len(t1[1])}: {t1[0]} -> {t1[1]}')
print(f'Max. count: {len(t2[1])}: {t2[0]} -> {t2[1]}')
```

For the following sample input:

```
K1 : V1
K1 : V2
K1 : V3
K1 : V1
K1 : V4
K1 : V1
K1 : V4
K2 : V5
K2 : V6
K2 : V6
K2 : V6
K3 : V2
K4 : V5
```

it prints:

```
{'K1': ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'], 'K2': ['V5', 'V6'], 'K3': ['V2'], 'K4': ['V5']}
Min. count: 1: K3 -> ['V2']
Max. count: 4: K1 -> ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4']
```